# HashSet contains() method

Tags: java, collections, set, contains, hashset

I executed below code and found the output was `false`.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Name {
    private String first, last;

    public Name(String first, String last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Name))
            return false;
        Name n = (Name) o;
        return n.first.equals(first) && n.last.equals(last);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Name> s = new HashSet<Name>();
        s.add(new Name("Donald", "Duck"));
        System.out.println(s.contains(new Name("Donald", "Duck")));
    }
}
```

I want to know how it behaves and why output is `false`.

Comment: You haven't overridden `hashCode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode()` method also along with `equals()`. Both the methods are used for proper functionality of `HashSet`, so must be overriden in a **user-defined class** if you are making that `class` as a `key`, else `hashCode()` of `Object` class is getting used and no two different `objects` can be considered as same as their `hashCode()` would always be different, and will for sure return `false`always in the case of `contains()`.

Answer (score 3):

In order for a `HashSet` (or `HashMap`, for that matter) to properly locate your object, you need to override the `hashCode()` method so that two object which are equal have the same hashCode. The canonical way of doing this looks like this (assuming `first` and `last` can't be `null`, like your `equals` method assumes:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + first.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + last.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Any `Hash` based data structure implementation (collection) in Java checks duplication based on two things :

**1 :** if `equals` method returns `true` for any of elements which are already stored in collection.

**2 :** if the `hashCode` method returns the `same integer value` for any of elements which are already stored in collection.

So in your case you haven't overridden the hashCode method, it means it will try to check hashCode equality using hashCode method default implementation of `Object` class which is not aware of your `last` and `first` variables.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals()` method is ok, but you have missed to override `hashCode()` method, just override the `hashCode()` method, it will work. And don't forgot you always need to override both `equals() and hashCode()` or none of them to get the correct behavior. If you are planing to use your objects as a key in hashing mechanism than you must override both of them.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((last == null) ? 0 : last.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You must override `hashCode()` in every class that overrides `equals()`. Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract for `Object.hashCode()`, which will prevent your class from functioning properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including `HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable`.*

from Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch

Comment: put in code format give four space each line of code

Answer (score 0):

You can also see how your code will be executed.

1. When you try to add element in set it calls the hash code and it gets bucket.
2. Once you get the hash value from hash code the overrided equals will be run  for all those who are having same hash token.

Hope this helps.