# Java contains() method returns False even though overridden equals() returns True

Tags: java, collections, equals, contains, hashset

I have an class called `Record` that consists of a vector of `Data` class objects.

Class `Data` has nothing but two fields:

```
Object value;
String name;
```

I override the equals method in the `Record` class as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.columnsOfData.size();i++) {
        System.out.println( ((Record) obj).columnsOfData.get(i).name + " OBJECT " + ((Record) obj).columnsOfData.get(i).value );
        System.out.println( columnsOfData.get(i).name + " THIS " + columnsOfData.get(i).value );
        if( !((((Record) obj).columnsOfData.get(i).name).equals(this.columnsOfData.get(i).name))   || !((((Record) obj).columnsOfData.get(i).value).equals(this.columnsOfData.get(i).value))) {
            check = false;
        }
    }
    
    return (obj instanceof Record && check);
}
```

I initialize HashSet as follows:

```
Set<Record> answer = new HashSet<Record>()
```

and start testing

```
        Record r1 = new Record();
        r1.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new Double( 1.5 ),"gpa"));
        r1.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new String("John"),"name"));
        r1.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new Integer( 2 ),"id"));
        
        Record r2 = new Record();
        r2.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new Double( 1.5 ),"gpa"));
        r2.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new String("John"),"name"));
        r2.columnsOfData.add(new Data(new Integer( 2 ),"id"));

        System.out.println(r1.equals(r2)); //RETURNS TRUE
        answer.add(r1);
        System.out.println(answer.contains(r2)); //RETURNS FALSE
```

Any help understanding where the issue is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also you also overriding `hashCode`?

Comment: @JacobG.No No I'm not, I'm not quite sure why I'm supposed to do that, or how to implement it exactly

Comment: It could be that your 2 objects are equal, but they are not the same instance.

Comment: @ThallsEternal how do I go around fixing that?

Comment: You could create another class that inherits from List<> (or whatever datatype answer is) and then override the contains method when accepting an object of type Record

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: The `obj instanceof Record` should be the *first* thing to check, not the last thing. Most notably, it should happen before you are performing the `(Record) obj` type casts. Besides that, use neither, `new Double( 1.5 )`, `new String("John")`, nor `new Integer( 2 )`. Use `1.5`, `"John"`, and `2`. The actual problem has been explained already, without a proper `hashCode()` implementation, you can’t use `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override also the hashCode method. It should work.
You can find an explanation here:
[HashSet contains() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470515/hashset-contains-method)

Answer (score 0):

HashSet relies on the contract that `hashCode`s of equal objects are equal. That is, if a.equals(b) returns true, then a.hashCode() must be the same as b.hashCode()

You should override the hashCode() method of Record to use it in a HashSet